# How to get overlay on Video Player in activity

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

On Video players such as Youtube, I often see that when the user taps on the video view a sort of overlay shows up where the user can choose actions like: “share”, “add to playlist”, “pause”, etc. Basically it’s whatever the developer wants. The developer seems to be able to choose what the icons are, where they go, etc.

I would like to know how it’s done. For example, are they using a VideoView with an overlay? Are they using a FrameLayout with a VideoView and a RelativeLayout on top of the VideoView? I just need some advice in the right direction as I don’t know where to start. Thanks. For simplicity, I am looking to add a **Youtube** style video player to my activity. And by **Youtube** style, I am referring to the aforementioned interactions.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how it’s done

I am sure that the implementation varies widely.

> For example, are they using a VideoView with an overlay?

AFAIK, few professional-grade apps use `VideoView`, simply because `VideoView` offers little in the way of events or control. More likely, they are using something else backed by `MediaPlayer` or third-party media libraries (e.g., ExoPlayer).

> Are they using a FrameLayout with a VideoView and a RelativeLayout on top of the VideoView?

No, because that would be two `VideoView` widgets. However, whatever their video surface is probably resides in a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`, with the overlay as another child of that same container, though I am sure that there are other approaches.

You are welcome to use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to try to learn more about the view hierarchy of particular apps of interest.